# Does this Interrupt Disable/Enable pair from TI's gamepad example project accomplish anything?

Tags: c, arm, embedded, texas-instruments

This code from TI's ek-tm4c123gxl usb-dev-gamepad CCS example wraps an volatile enum assignment to g_iGamepadState in an interrupt disable/enable pair. To me it looks like a bug; that it should instead be wrapping the send report function USBDHIDGamepadSendReport() to prevent mid-send interruption. As is I would assume this it's preventing the interrupt of a single store instruction, which would be redundant.

Below is the all code which references the enum...

```
volatile enum {
    eStateNotConfigured,            // Not yet configured.
    eStateIdle,                     // Connected, not waiting on data to be sent
    eStateSuspend,                  // Suspended
    eStateSending                   // Connected, waiting on data to be sent out
} g_iGamepadState;

...

//*****************************************************************************
//
// Handles asynchronous events from the HID gamepad driver.
//
// \param pvCBData is the event callback pointer provided during
// USBDHIDGamepadInit().  This is a pointer to our gamepad device structure
// (&g_sGamepadDevice).
// \param ui32Event identifies the event we are being called back for.
// \param ui32MsgData is an event-specific value.
// \param pvMsgData is an event-specific pointer.
//
// This function is called by the HID gamepad driver to inform the application
// of particular asynchronous events related to operation of the gamepad HID
// device.
//
// \return Returns 0 in all cases.
//
//*****************************************************************************
uint32_t GamepadHandler(void *pvCBData, uint32_t ui32Event,
        uint32_t ui32MsgData, void *pvMsgData) {
    switch (ui32Event) {
    case USB_EVENT_CONNECTED: {
        g_iGamepadState = eStateIdle;
        break;
    }
    case USB_EVENT_DISCONNECTED: {
        g_iGamepadState = eStateNotConfigured;
        break;
    }
    case USB_EVENT_TX_COMPLETE: {
        g_iGamepadState = eStateIdle;
        break;
    }
    case USB_EVENT_SUSPEND: {
        g_iGamepadState = eStateSuspend;
        break;
    }
    case USB_EVENT_RESUME: {
        g_iGamepadState = eStateIdle;
        break;
    }

    ...

    default: {
        break;
    }
    }

    return (0);
}

...

int main(void) {

    ...

    // Not configured initially.
    g_iGamepadState = eStateNotConfigured;

    ...


    while (1) {
        //
        // Wait here until USB device is connected to a host.
        //
        if (g_GamepadState == eStateIdle) {

            ...

            USBDHIDGamepadSendReport(&g_sGamepadDevice, &sReport,
                    sizeof(sReport));

            //
            // Now sending data but protect this from an interrupt since
            // it can change in interrupt context as well.
            //
            IntMasterDisable();
            g_iGamepadState = eStateSending;
            IntMasterEnable();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The placement of the interrupt disable/enable bugs me too. In the example, what happens if you get the interrupt for the TX_COMPLETE response after calling USBHIDGamepadSendReport but before IntMasterDisable()? You'd get stuck with the eStateSending state.

Comment: @Prismatic with TIs code, it's usually best to follow the same order they do

Comment: I encounter an issue when I do though. With their example, my gamepad controller stops working after awhile (not after a set amount of time). Debugger seems to show its stuck in the main while loop. The state is not NotConfigured, Suspend, or Idle so I'm guessing its stuck with Sending. Its possible the interrupt disable/enable is placed incorrectly and causing my issue. Probably better to post on e2e as the TI engineers browse there though.

Comment: @Prismatic I'll go ahead and cross-post this to e2e, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

From TI's [E2E forum](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/tiva_arm/f/908/t/574141)...

> I think you are correct. This may be a bug.

It is possible for an Idle TX event to return between sending the report and changing to the sending state enum, which would then never leave the sending state. This explanation seems to make the most sense as to why the disable/enable interrupt pair is there in the first place.